# Codename One - TextModeLayout on iOS and validation error feedback

Tags: codenameone

The `TextModeLayout`, on iOS, produces only a red cross on the right of a text field to indicate an invalid input (if we use a `Validator`).

In general, this is fine. However, I added a `LengthConstraint(8)` to a password field and I'm worried if users understand that there is a requirement for lengtness.

Is there a standard way in the iOS design to provide the user the cause of a validation error, or the only way is to use the Material Design also on iOS (that means set to `true` the theme const `textComponentOnTopBool`)?

Code:

```
   TextModeLayout tl = new TextModeLayout(2, 1);
    Container credentials = new Container(tl);
    credentials.setUIID("MyContainer01");
    TextComponent email = new TextComponent().label("FieldEmail");
    TextComponent password = new TextComponent().label("FieldPassword");
    Validator val = new Validator();
    val.addConstraint(email, RegexConstraint.validEmail());
    val.addConstraint(password, new LengthConstraint(8));
    val.addSubmitButtons(loginButton);
    email.getField().setConstraint(TextField.EMAILADDR);
    password.getField().setConstraint(TextField.PASSWORD);
    InputComponent.group(email, password);
    credentials.add(email);
    credentials.add(password);
```

Comment: I think that's more of an iOS question than a Codename One question. The iOS input is something we need to refine a bit and that's a good target for that.